# R code for finding residuals in mixed anova?

Tags: r, anova, mixed

I am wondering how I can check the normality of residuals (I’m using R).

I have a between subject factor (experiment) and two within factors (day and treatment). What I am looking for is the difference of percentage between experiments. ID is the individuals tested for.

I used the `rstatix` package with the code but the code doesn’t include residual:

```
anova_test(data = data, dv = percent, wid = ID, between = experiment, within = c(day, treatment))
```

And this one from the `afex` package also gives the same results with no residuals:

```
aov_car(percent ~ experiment * day * treatment + Error(ID/(day * treatment)), data = data)
```

Any help with how to write a code in any package that would give me the residuals is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide some data to test!

Comment: Have you tried `summary(x)` where x is your test object? `summary()` outputs residuals when using `aov()` from the `stats` package, hopefully it works for `rstatix` too.

Comment: @LeroyTyrone I tried it but neither of them provide residuals unfortunately.

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.